# ASP.NET catch the submit action

Tags: c#, asp.net, submit

I'm a super beginner ASP.NET developer. I read that on every submit the request parameters are being populated to the controls and instead of reading the "Response.Form[]" parameters I can read the input parameters from the control itself.

Are there any events that I can catch all the submits before and after the magic happens? 
Which method on the server side is activated that perform this magic? 
Can I override it (for fun)?

Thanks,
   Ronny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are talking about the function of Viewstate and how control values are persisted.

This is a [diagram](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304122759/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050504-1.aspx) that will show you the page load order for ASP.NET

For you, if you want to look before viewstate is loaded, you can work inside the Page_Init method.

Answer (score 0):

see few tutorials

http://aspalliance.com/quickstart/aspplus/

http://quickstart.developerfusion.co.uk/QuickStart/

In asp.net all event, result in post-back. So, you can handle them in Page_Load, but it's classic way. For fun you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET maps HTML input field values from the `Request.Form` collection to server control properties, such as `TextBox.Text` between the [`Page.InitComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initcomplete.aspx) and [`Page.PreLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preload.aspx) events, as detailed in the ever-linkable [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

The actual mapping takes place in the non-virtual private method `Page.ProcessPostData`, so there's no real hook for modifying that process. (You can see this by [downloading Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and reviewing the `Page.ProcessRequestMain` method.)

If you want to perform custom processing before or after the mapping, you can add a handlers to the appropriate events or override the associated virtual methods ([`Page.OnInitComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.oninitcomplete.aspx) and [`Page.OnPreLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.onpreload.aspx)).